# Creating a responsive CSS footer using gradient and bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

[image]

I’m using Bootstrap and CSS to make a footer like this image, the problem is it has to be responsive. How am I going to do that curve with CSS?

Here is what I'm trying

jsfiddle.net/warpoluido/8wyLg/

Comment: Elliptical gradient? Multiple bg images? What have you tried?

Comment: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Comment: Here's an idea: hire a web developer perhaps? Seriously though, please show us what you've already tried. No-one's going to write it for you without having seen at least some initiative to solve the problem on your part.

Comment: @next2u Not a border-radius issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the working demo link.

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8wyLg/2/)

HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div class='left'></div>
    <div class='right'></div>
</footer>
```